# real time notifications between mobile app and web app

Tags: websocket, synchronization, real-time-updates, android-push-notification

I'm developing an application in which users can send reports to the admins and the admin has a web panel from where he can check the reports from the users. So I need real-time notifications between my mobile app and website so what do I need to do? I searched about it and found the web socket server as the solution for my problem but I'm quite confused that from where I should start. I'm using MySQL database with PHP as a backend language for creating APIs for my mobile app and also a retrofit library to build the connection with a database.

I didn't try out anything for this because I don't know how I'll start.

Comment: It will never be true real-time, but I don't think that's what you mean either. What exactly are you having trouble with? Going from the mobile to the web site should just be a normal post message, no?

Comment: I wanna know what should I do, if I  send a msg from the mobile app, it should be shown on the website at the same time so in a sense it's a real-time notification.